# c++ return by value vs return by reference

Tags: c++

If I have two functions like:

**1.**

```
vector<Student_Info> extract_failed(vector<Student_Info>& students) {
    return students;
}
```

**2.**

```
vector<Student_Info>& extract_failed(vector<Student_Info>& students) {
    return students;
}
```

Is it correct to say that function 1 is `returning by value`, which means a copy of `students` will be created and returned and function 2 is `returning by reference`?

Comment: Yes. The answer to this question is so short I have to add this statement or SO won't let me post it.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thanks! I will just delete my question then.

Comment: Yes - that's what it means logically . . . but, the compiler might move the return value rather than copy it if it were just going to go out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it correct to say that function 1 is returning by value, which means a copy of students will be created and returned and function 2 is returning by reference?

Yes, it is correct. Another way to phrase it, which I prefer, is to say that 1 returns a value, and 2 returns a reference.

Answer (score 0):

**YES**

Although **2.** in its current form would make sence if you plan to use the return value (something like `print(extract_failed(students));` or `for(const auto& s : extract_failed(students)`).

Meanwhile, some scenarios may be confusing, since you can do something like

```
auto& new_students = extract_failed(students);
```

and you'll have two names in the same scope for the same vector.